# Is there a regex to match a string that contains A but does not contain B

Tags: regex, contains, inverse

My problem is that I want to check the browserstring with pure regex.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.0; en-us; Xoom Build/HRI39) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.13
```

Should match

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRG83) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

Should not match

My tried solution is: `/?((?<=Android)(?:[^])*?(?=Mobile))/i`
but it matches exactly wrong.

Comment: what language, regex flavour? http://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html

Comment: It is not so easy: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/8186424/241506][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8186424/241506

Comment: What do you want to express with `(?:[^])*?` ?

Answer (score 104):

You use look ahead assertions to check if a string contains a word or not.

If you want to assure that the string contains "Android" at some place you can do it like this:

```
^(?=.*Android).*
```

You can also combine them, to ensure that it contains "Android" at some place AND "Mobile" at some place:

```
^(?=.*Android)(?=.*Mobile).*
```

If you want to ensure that a certain word is NOT in the string, use the negative look ahead:

```
^(?=.*Android)(?!.*Mobile).*
```

This would require the word "Android to be in the string and the word "Mobile" is not allowed in the string. The `.*` part matches then the complete string/row when the assertions at the beginning are true.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v9bp)

Answer (score 3):

With some implementations of regular expressions, you can use a negative lookbehind assertion.
Per the docs, a negative lookbehind written as `(?<!...)` matches only if the current position in the string is not preceded by a match for `...`

Here's a Python interactive script showing how to use negative lookbehind with your sample strings:

```
>>> s = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.0; en-us; Xoom Build/HRI39) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.13"
>>> bool(re.search(r'Android.*(?<! Mobile) Safari', s))
True

>>> t = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRG83) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1"
>>> bool(re.search(r'Android.*(?<! Mobile) Safari', t))
False
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just break it up

```
if ((m/Android/i) && (m/Safari/i) && !(m/Mobile Safari/i))
```

That said, depending on regex flaviour, you could combine that

```
if ((m/Android/i) && (m/(?<!Mobile )Safari/i))
```

or even

```
if (m/Android.*(?<!Mobile )Safari/i)
```

FYI see [Lookahead/lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

---

**Update** Tested these fine with Perl5 regex flavour (arguably the most popular flavour):

```
perl -ne 'print "$. yes\n" if m/Android.*(?<!Mobile )Safari/i'
```

Shows:

```
1 yes
```

for the given input in the OP

Comment: Tested it now with Perl5 compatible regexen