# For the love of BASH, regex, locate & find - contains A not B

Tags: regex, bash, find, locate

**Goal**: Regex pattern for use with `find` and `locate` that "Contains A but not B"

So I have a `bash` script that manipulates a few video files.
In its current form, I create a variable to act on later with a `for` loop that works well:

```
if [ "$USE_FIND" = true ]; then
    vid_files=$(find "${DIR}" -type f -regex ".*\.\(mkv\|avi\|ts\|mp4\|m2ts\)")
else
    vid_files=$(locate -ir "${DIR}.*\.\(mkv\|avi\|ts\|mp4\|m2ts\)")
fi
```

So "contains A" is any one of the listed extensions.

I'd like to add to a condition where if a certain string (B) is contained the file isn't added to the array (can be a directory or a filename).

I've spent some time with lookaheads trying to implement this to no avail. So an example of "not contains B" as "Robot" - I've used different forms of `.*(?!Robot).*`

e.g. `".*\(\?\!Robot\).*\.\(mkv\|avi\|ts\|mp4\|m2ts\)"` for `find` but it doesn't work.

I've sort of exhausting regex101.com, terminal and `chmod +x` at this point and would welcome some help. I think it's the case that's it's called through a `bash` script causing me the difficulty.

One of my many sources of reference in trying to sort this:
Ref: [Is there a regex to match a string that contains A but does not contain B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240765/is-there-a-regex-to-match-a-string-that-contains-a-but-does-not-contain-b)

Comment: How about, instead of trying to find a regex, using a `-not` clause?

Comment: There is no lookahead in BRE, ERE, POSIX

Comment: Agreeing with @BenjaminW. here - You could just do `find "${DIR}" -type f -not -name Robot -name mkv -name avi -name ts...`

Comment: you can also pipe the results into `grep -v`

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions on `find` but I need to solve also for `locate` or handle it later at the `for` loop which is my current workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to avoid the use `find` inside a process substitution to build a list of files, as, while this is admittedly rare, filenames could contain newlines.

You could use an array, which will handle file names without issues (assuming the array is later expanded properly).

```
declare -a vid_files=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' file 
do
  ! [[ "$file" =~ Robot ]] || continue
  vid_files+=("$file")
done < <(find "${DIR}" -type f -regex ".*\.\(mkv\|avi\|ts\|mp4\|m2ts\)" -print0)
```

The `-print0` option of find generates a null byte to separate the file names, and the `-d ''` option of `read` allows a null byte to be used as a record separator (both obviously go together).

You can get the list of files using `"${vid_files[@]}"` (double quotes are important to prevent word splitting).  You can also iterate over the list easily :

```
for file in "${vid_files[@]}"
do
  echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: Hi @Fred - I appreciate your approach. I also agree with your identification of the possible newline character but I do know that's not in play.

Comment: Code gets copy and pasted all the time, and corner cases are irrelevant until, one day, they are.  This being said, you can use `grep -v` as suggested in the comments if you do not mind using a newline-separated list.