# Match if string contains one substring followed by another using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match one substring followed by another in a string input at word boundaries using regex. For e.g.  if
`string_1 = "I will give you a call in case I need some help in future"`
and if 2 substrings are "will" and "in case I need"
it should return true for string 1
but should return false for string below

```
string_2 = "in case I need some help I will call you"
```

I need a case insensitive match and can only use regex.

It should also return false for the below since it does not contain "in case I need" followed by the "will"

```
string_3 = "I will let you know" 

string_4 = "I will let you know in case we need"
```

I have looked at [Is there a regex to match a string that contains A but does not contain B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240765/is-there-a-regex-to-match-a-string-that-contains-a-but-does-not-contain-b) but unable to determine how I can do look ahead/ look backward for my scenario. That post covers when 2 strings are present without determining if one follows another.
Need the solution in python and cant use substring/find etc, so need to be a regex

```
str = 'I will give you a call in case I need some help in future' 

result = bool(re.search(r'^(?=.*\bwill\b)(?=.*\bin case I need\b).*', str)) 

print(result)
```

Above matches presence of "will" and "in case I need" without a order. I need  order to be enforced and one string to be followed by another i.e. "will" to be followed by "in case I need".

Comment: Simple: `re.search(r'\bwill\b.*\bin case I need\b', s)`

Comment: This works great, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

That complicated regexp is only needed because the order doesn't matter. If order matters, it's much simpler:

```
re.search(r'pattern1.*pattern2', string_to_search)
```

will look for `pattern1` followed by `pattern2`.

Comment: Thanks, with the addition of \b, this solves the question posted