# python regex match A but not B in any order

Tags: python, regex

This question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240765/is-there-a-regex-to-match-a-string-that-contains-a-but-does-not-contain-b) but I can't seem to be able to adopt it to my use case.

I want to match to a string that contains the word "reset" but not password. For example suppose I have the following two:

```py
queries = ["reset my password", "reset my account please.", "password reset"]
for q in queries:
    print(is_reset(q))
```

should output `False, True, False` where `is_reset` would contain the regex.

The regex that I tried was:

```
matches = re.search("(?=reset)(?!.*password)", text)
if matches:
    print("Matched")
else:
    print("No match")
```

The above seems to have an issue with the last query. Also I am blindly copying the regex, couls someone explain what the regex above/ answer means?

Comment: can you just use `'reset' in q and 'password' not in q`

Comment: @Reza oh. I uhh feel super stupid now. Guess I overcomplicated things there. Well at least I learnt something about regex.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your current pattern `(?=reset)(?!.*password)` is that while it does correctly have lookaheads which assert that `reset` is present and `password` is *not* present, the pattern itself is zero width, and so will never match any content which is not zero width.  I would use this pattern:

```
^(?!.*\bpassword\b).*\breset\b.*$
```

This matches any input with `reset` appearing anywhere, and it has a negative assertion at the beginning to exclude `password` from being present.

Sample script:

```
queries = ["reset my password", "reset my account please.", "password reset"]
for q in queries:
    matches = re.search(r'^(?!.*\bpassword\b).*\breset\b.*$', q)
    if matches:
        print("Matched:  " + q)
    else:
       print("No match: " + q)
```

This prints:

```
No match: reset my password
Matched:  reset my account please.
No match: password reset
```

Comment: I think he did not want `password reset` to match.

Comment: @leoOrion I have fixed my answer, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I suggest `\breset\b`, for the same reason you've enclosed `password` in word boundaries (avoid matching `preset`, for example), and don't believe you need `$`.

Comment: Agree. I was going to edit, but felt that my previous version already got the point across.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with regex, you have to a negative lookup on `passsword` and positive lookup on `reset` -

`^(?=.*reset)(?!.*password).*`

This should work.

`(?=.*reset)` -> Matches when there is `reset`.
`(?!.*password).*` -> Dont match when there is `password`

The main problem was you were always expecting reset to be not have anything before it. add a `.*` before `reset` to indicate it can have characters before it as well. Similarly `password` can have charcters after it as well. hence the `.*` after `password`