# Regex to check a word is present in line exactly three times

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to create a Regex. I have 4 `Yes/No` questions and I'm storing the answers in a text field, like `YesYesNoNo` or `YesNoNoYes` etc.

I want my Regex to check if the answer line contains exactly **3** `Yes`.

I have tried

```
Yes{3}, [r'(Yes)\W+']
```

and some other silly options.

Comment: You can try: `^(?:(?:No)*Yes){2}`

Comment: Your title says `three times`, but the questions says `exactly 2 yes`.

Comment: No, use `^(?:(?:No)*Yes){2}(?!.*Yes)` or `^(?:(?:No)*Yes){2}(?:No)*$`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to match when a string is present twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186384/regex-to-match-when-a-string-is-present-twice)

Comment: @0stone0: That's not correct dupe, please verify.

Comment: It is correct, @anubhava, https://stackoverflow.com/a/8188385/3832970 answers this question.

Comment: Which is a horrible regex to solve a simple problem

Comment: Sorry I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to restrict your matches to exactly 3 `Yes` in the input text that only contains `No` and `Yes`, consider this regex:

```
^(?:(?:No)*Yes){3}(?!.*Yes)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/U6SPy4/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(?:No)*`: Match 0 or more `No` strings
- `Yes`: Match text `Yes`
- `){3}`: non-capture group. Repeat this group `3` times
- `(?!.*Yes)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have another instance of `Yes` string after matching `Yes` 3 times.

If lookahead is not available on your regex flavor, you can use this regex:

```
^(?:(?:No)*Yes){3}(?:No)*$
```

Comment: at least 2 does not solve my problem. I have conditions like;
exact 2 times - do this
exact 3 times - do that

Comment: I have provided regex for `exactly 2 Yes` also which is `^(?:(?:No)*Yes){2}(?!.*Yes)`. For 3 just make it `^(?:(?:No)*Yes){3}(?!.*Yes)`. Did you test that?

Comment: You are a hero! Thanks, your answer solved the problem.